# Low Reputation leads to not being taken seriously

Tags: discussion, reputation

I really noticed that having low reputation usually leads other people to ignore your answer (although I was definitely sure that it was correct and I've written the source of answer too). Of course the reason of low reputation doesn't always mean that you're not well informed, but for example in my situation I was fresh in a new community.
Of course, sometimes having low reputation leads other members to ignore your questions too.

So is there an efficient solution to this?

Comment: *So is there an efficient solution to this?* Gaining rep of course. Do I miss something? Because I don't see a question here. (I'm yet to vote)

Comment: Oh, and are you sure it's [only](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A0) you?

Comment: Do you have any evidence of your assertion that low reputation leads to ignored answers? Note that a couple of examples would be anecdotes rather than evidence.

Comment: Which particular question or answer are you referring to?

Comment: You only have [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840400/yii2-submit-form-on-field-click/32841776#32841776) and that was a 1-line answer to your own question  that consisted of: "Just had to change the tags in the function above to js and it worked." How do you know low reputation stops you getting votes other than on this?

Comment: How did you observe this behaviour? That is, something that shows statistical significance? Are you certain it isn't any other factor, such as quality of question/answer?

Comment: This is a dupe of the "how do I gain rep on SE" question.

Comment: See? Your behaviour of rating my question 'down', even though it's serious is because I don't have any reputation. If someone else with 1000 reputation asked the same question would've gotten a thousand answer.

Comment: Lack of facts and wrong base assumptions lead to not being taken seriously. I would have downvoted this even if you had 10000000 reputation.

Comment: And there is a syndrome I don't know what to call that when a question gets a 'down' vote, every viewer gives it another down rate.

Comment: Nonsense @Shadow Wizard

Comment: @Ragheb please stop seeing everyone else is at fault and you're right. The downvote I gave now isn't because someone else did. Neither is it because you are a one-rep user. There are numerous downvoted - sorry, I mean *heavily* downvoted - answers from Jeff Atwood himself here.

Comment: @RaghebAlKilany The reason that downvoted posts have a tendency to attract more downvotes is because downvoted posts tend to be bad and merit being downvoted.  Note that some experienced users have done the experiment of creating a new account to see how they get treated posting quality posts as a new user and they've tended to have positive experiences and not noticed harsher voting.

Comment: The only answer where you provide a source link is [What's the difference between "won't" and "wouldn't"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/276720). It has a single downvote. It is not a very good answer. The other answer is better and tries to explain the differences. Your answer missed the point completely (the difference is **not** about being polite). The accepted answer to another (duplicate) question ["won't" vs. "wouldn't"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20491) is a much better answer.

Comment: @Ragheb: The term you're looking for is "dogpiling". It happens sometimes, but I think you're concluding that that's what's happening to you. Your one answer is very short on details, which is why it probably got downvoted. (That the Meta effect hasn't kicked in and got it many more is probably a testament to the fact that it's at least marginally useful.) Your question here is certainly getting downvotes because it seems like another thinly veiled complaint about downvotes.

Comment: [Just an example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32859467/993547): how did new answerers 'not taken serious'? Wasn't it the high-rep user with an answer that actually explained something who wasn't taken serious?

Comment: I said before It happened to me three times, but why bother giving proof ?

Comment: At one point I had zero rep on EL&U. I felt like an outsider but I liked the answers the posted, and I had a few questions I wanted to ask too. But before I did, I looked at how the site worked, I read old posts, looked at posts which were upvoted, and those that were downvoted. I got a feel of the site, so I posted and I was HUMBLE. I had many downvotes in the beginning, but the upvotes I did receive encouraged me, and convinced me I was doing something right.

Comment: Everyone here starts from 1 rep, yep, they were all low-rep at one time. But how did they get to their current rep? Here, on Stack Exchange, we mostly don't judge people, **we judge the post**. We don't (really) care if they have 1 rep, or 10k rep as long as their post are good/useful/detailed. Heck, I even downvoted an answer by 10k since it's not correct due to question being unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good question, one asked clearly and concisely with code supplied and specific issue(s) explained, may get upvotes just for being asked properly.  If they deal with common issues and others are having similar problems, they'll get even more upvotes.

Similarly, clear and concise answers with specific solutions are most likely to get upvoted.  The amount of rep has little to do with that.  It's all about how usable your answer is, and how easy it is to implement.

Meta, on the other hand, is a completely different animal.  Here, up and down votes are meant to indicate agreement and disagreement with what you're asking.  This question received several downvotes only because users disagree with your statement.

Keep plugging away.  Keep answering questions clearly and concisely.  Keep asking detailed questions that seek **help** and not **free code**.  Your rep will increase.

Answer (score 10):

I disagree with your statement that new, low-reputation users are not taken seriously. Often I find that new users with a good answer get more sympathy up-votes in order to outscore a high-reputation user's answer.

The thing I do see is that it is hard to get used to the community, how the site works and how one should react on down-votes and closed questions. Those who do pick up the message given and improve will most likely get quite some reputation as they go, since they know what is expected from them.

See it like this: if you enter a soccer field and want to play along, you have to follow the rules of the ones playing. If your idea of the game is different than the current players, they will not like your contribution. Here it means they will not up-vote and may even down-vote you.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a rant on discrimination of low rep users. Might as well restart the Civil War now... Anyways, questions on Stack Overflow or any active site will usually have low views due to the fact that new questions pop up really fast. Most of the time, your question gets "kicked" from the first page of your tag(s) and other users don't see them.

If you posted a question, someone will see it whether by flag, hot question, reviewing, etc. Some users only scan the most recent ones then just wait for new questions to pop up. Others like me will scan multiple pages to see any questions that capture their interest/is answerable and we might see your question.

> Of course the reason of low reputation doesn't always mean that you're not well informed, but for example in my situation I was fresh in a new community.

So what? We are all humans (unless you're a spam robot) that will happily provide information to each other. Rep is only so you can do more things with the site as the community can trust you with not destroying the site, spamming, etc. Naturally, we're all the same even Jon Skeet with his arrogant score of 800k+ rep and the new users with the starting rep of 1.

> Of course, sometimes having low reputation leads other members to ignore your questions too.

As said above, people will love to help others like you and me. Rep should not be a concern here. Rep is suppose to add some fun and motivation to SE, not a way to distinguish what you should see and what not to see. Anyways, if your question doesn't get viewed a lot, at least you earned the Tumbleweed badge right? :)

Anyways, most users with common sense will help others regardless of rep. So no, there isn't a solution because there is no problem. If there is, it has been already been solved: our love and kindness and our passion to help others in need.